# Count Query Reciepe/Ingredients

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

basically I've been working on an SQL question which is asking to display each ingredient along with the total number of recipes it's included in. It also must only include the ingredients that occur more than 10 times and descending order of ingredient popularity and ascending order of `ingrdesc`.

the tables are as followed:

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredient
(

idI NUMBER              constraint pk_Ingredient PRIMARY KEY ,

ingrDesc VARCHAR2(100)  constraint nn1Ingredient not null
);


CREATE TABLE Recipe
(

idR NUMBER                constraint pk_recipe PRIMARY KEY ,

recipeTitle VARCHAR2(200)  constraint nn1Recipe not null,
prepText VARCHAR2(4000),

cuisineType VARCHAR2(50),
mealType VARCHAR2(30) DEFAULT NULL,

CONSTRAINT ch_mealType CHECK (mealType IN ('starter', 'main', 'dessert', null))
);


CREATE TABLE RecpIngr
(

idR NUMBER ,

hidI NUMBER ,

CONSTRAINT pk_RecpIngr PRIMARY KEY (idR, idI),

CONSTRAINT fk1RecpIngr_recipe foreign key(idR) references Recipe,

CONSTRAINT fk2RecpIngr_ingredient foreign key(idI) references Ingredient
)
organization index;
```

So far I have this query:

```
SELECT ingrDesc,
COUNT (idR) As num_of_recipes
FROM RespIngr
WHERE num_of_recipes <10
ORDER BY num_of_recipes DES, ingrDes ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ingrDesc,
COUNT (idR) As num_of_recipes
FROM RespIngr
GROUP BY ingrDesc
HAVING COUNT (idR) > 10
ORDER BY num_of_recipes DESC, ingrDesc ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. You show a query from table `RespIngr` but you don't mention such a table. You show a table `RecpIngr` but that doesn't contain the field `ingrDesc`.

To get the fields you show, the query must contain a join of the table that contains the recipes and ingredients and the table that contains the description of the ingredients.

```
with
RCount( IngID, RecipeCount )as(
    select  hidI, count(*)
    from    RecpIngr
    group by hidI
    having count(*) > 10
)
select  i.ingrDesc as "Ingredient", rc.RecipeCount as "Number of Recipes"
from    Ingredient  i
join    RCount      rc
    on  rc.IngID = i.idI;
```